# Square version of \subsetneq

Tags: symbols

Does anyone know how to make a 'square version' of `\subsetneq`?
I tried `\sqsubsetneq`, but it doesn't work.

Thanks!
Joon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the [mathabx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathabx) package:

[image]

For such things I highly recommend trying: `texdoc symbols`

Code:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}

  $X \sqsubsetneq B$

\end{document}
```

**Edit:** just to complete, here is a print screen from the documentation cited.

[image]

Comment: With the usual caveat that this changes *all* math symbols. See [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)